# UIImagePickerController from UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, camera

When I press button, camera open but if I press cancel, or after I take a photo and press USE, camera stuck. I want to dismiss, to remove camera and to use image for my ImageView.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    scrtImg.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [picker2.view removeFromSuperview];
}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [picker2.view removeFromSuperview];
}


- (IBAction)openCamera:(id)sender
{    
    picker2 = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    picker2.delegate = self;
    [picker2 setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    [self addSubview:picker2.view];
    [picker2 release];  
}
```

If I use this code on ViewController, it works great, but in UIView it doesn't work. Help me, I need to open camera from UIView, and to USE image in UIView. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Once add the UIView in window and then try. It may work.